# Build Errors Intel C++ (Knights Corner) ipo: warning #11010: file format not recognized

Tags: c++, linker, intel

I am trying to write a code to be build on **3 systems** which mainly differentiate on the basis of their Register Lengths:

1. SSE (128 Bits)
2. AVX (256 Bits)
3. MIC (Intel's Knights Corner 512 Bits)

My **Makefile** builds the executable depending on the system of choice, which can be chosen from **config.mk** which looks like:

```
MIC=0           # 0 = no MIC kernels        | 1 = build MIC kernels
AVX=0           # 0 = no AVX kernels        | 1 = build AVX kernels
SSE=0           # 0 = no SSE kernels        | 1 = build SSE kernels
```

My Main Makefile is:

```
#   CONFIGURE BUILD SYSTEM
include config.mk
CXXFLAGS = -O2 -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-format -Wall

ifeq '$(strip $(SSE))' '1'
    CXXFLAGS += -msse4.2
    TAG = LIMA
    #@echo "$(CXXFLAGS)"
endif

ifeq '$(strip $(AVX))' '1'
    CXXFLAGS += -mavx
    TAG = SANDY
    #@echo "$(CXXFLAGS)"
endif

ifeq '$(strip $(MIC))' '1'
    CXXFLAGS += -mmic
    TAG = MIC
    #@echo "$(CXXFLAGS)"
endif

CC       = icc
CXX      = icpc
INCLUDES = -I./src/includes
CXXFLAGS := $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES)
DEFINES  = -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBUG
LINKER   = $(CXX) -liomp5 -lpthread
LIBS     = 
LFLAGS   = 

#   BUILD PARAMETERS
TARGET     = SpMvM_$(TAG)
SRC_DIR    = ./src
MAKE_DIR   = ./
Q         ?= @
BUILD_DIR  = ./$(TAG)

VPATH = $(SRC_DIR)
OBJ = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o, $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)) ))

${TARGET}: $(BUILD_DIR) $(OBJ)
    @echo "===>  LINKING  $(TARGET)"
    @echo "$(Q)${LINKER} ${LFLAGS} -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ) $(LIBS)"
    $(Q)${LINKER} ${LFLAGS} -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ) $(LIBS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o:  %.cpp
    @echo "===>  COMPILE  $@"
    @echo "$(Q)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@"
    $(Q)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 

$(BUILD_DIR):
    @mkdir $(BUILD_DIR)

.PHONY: clean distclean

clean:
    @echo "===>  CLEAN"
    @rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
    @rm -f tags
    @rm -f $(TARGET)
    @rm -f *~

distclean: clean
    @echo "===> DIST CLEAN"
    @rm -f $(TARGET)
    @rm -f tags

clean_dir:
    @echo "===> CLEAN DIR"
    @rm -rf LIMA/ SANDY/ MIC/

clean_all:
    @echo "===> CLEAN ALL"
    @rm -f  SpMvM_LIMA SpMvM_SANDY
    @rm -rf LIMA/ SANDY/ MIC/
```

The **config.mk** helps in choosing the right compiler flags (-msse4.2, -mavx, -mmic).

The test code is a simple "HELLO WORLD" application in c++. It works with no errors on **SSE** and **AVX** systems.

When I tried to compile on **MIC**, the following error shows up:

```
===>  COMPILE  MIC/main.o
@icpc -O2 -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-format -Wall -openmp -mmic  -I./src/includes -c ./src/main.cpp  -o MIC/main.o
===>  LINKING  SpMvM_MIC
@icpc -liomp5 -lpthread -o SpMvM_MIC ./MIC/main.o
ipo: warning #11010: file format not recognized for ./MIC/main.o
ld: ./MIC/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 181)
ld: ./MIC/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 181)
ld: ./MIC/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 181)
ld: ./MIC/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 181)
ld: ./MIC/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 181)
ld: ./MIC/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 181)
ld: ./MIC/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 181)
./MIC/main.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
make: *** [SpMvM_MIC] Error 1
```

I have searched enough to understand that **ipo** errors have something to do with compiling and linking on different system. But it doesn't make sense in my case. The executable (SpMvM_$(TAG)) and Objects files ($(BUILD_DIR)/) are created on each system and they are all named with a suffice ($(TAG) = LIMA, SANDY, MIC) depending on the system to be used. **As a result on object file from one system overlaps in linking or usage to the other**.

Can someone Please let me know with what is wrong?

Comment: You don't have the architecture specified on the link line.

Comment: @Steve-o Thanks for your reply. I got it. For any1else refer to [BUILDING APPS on MIC](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/building-a-native-application-for-intel-xeon-phi-coprocessors)